Terraform: Nested for_each in nested dynamic blocks
I have the following variable definition:
variable "rule-configuration" {
  description = "Configuration of the Firewall rules. The key is the name of the rule"
  type = map(object({
    priority           = number
    hub_prefix = string
    spoke_prefixes = list(object({
      name = string
      cidr = string
    }))
  }))
}

I have the following resource definition:
resource "azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group" "this" {
  name               = "xxx"
  firewall_policy_id = "xxx"
  priority           = 500

  dynamic "network_rule_collection" {
    for_each = var.firewall_configuration

    content {
      name     = each.key
      priority = each.value.priority
      action   = "Allow"

      dynamic "rule" {
        for_each = each.value.spoke_prefixes

        content {
          name                  = ??.value.name
          source_addresses      = [each.value.hub_prefix]
          destination_addresses = [??.value.cidr]
          protocols             = ["Any"]
          destination_ports     = ["*"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

How can I make the nested for_each in the nested dynamic block work?

Why are you downvoting? It is not very helpful to downvote but not provide any comment why you downvoted

Terraform allows to specify the iterator what allows to use it for a nested for_each:
resource "azurerm_firewall_policy_rule_collection_group" "this" {
  name               = "xxx"
  firewall_policy_id = "xxx"
  priority           = 500

  dynamic "network_rule_collection" {
    for_each = var.firewall_configuration
    iterator = firewall_configuration

    content {
      name     = firewall_configuration.key
      priority = firewall_configuration.value.priority
      action   = "Allow"

      dynamic "rule" {
        for_each = each.value.spoke_prefixes
        iterator = rule

        content {
          name                  = rule.value.name
          source_addresses      = [each.value.hub_prefix]
          destination_addresses = [rule.value.cidr]
          protocols             = ["Any"]
          destination_ports     = ["*"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

